# Replacing ArrayPool<T> for creating arrays without allocation

Tags: c#

I have small chunk of code for uploading a video file by reading the file in chunks and transferring it to the API. E.g. simplified

```
while (someflag)
{
    // open file stream
    reader.Seek(counterHowMuchIsTransferred, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(chunkSize);
    await reader.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(), cancellationToken);
}
```

Now the problem is that `ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Rent()` returns minimum requested size, which most of the times returns bigger array and breaks the file upload. How can I fix that **without** allocating new array every time `new byte[chunkSize]` because the `chunkSize` is always over **85K** and it will be allocated on LOH.

Comment: [`Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=net-6.0#system-io-stream-readasync(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32))?

Comment: Side note: on many frameworks, 85k may be well over the size where array-pool even bothers trying, vs just giving you a new array each time; this upper limit has increased in later frameworks, so it could still be useful in .NET 6 for example - just: don't *assume* that the pool *necessarily* helps; to get maximum pool benefit you *might* need to work instead with **discontiguous buffers**, i.e. `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` - which tracks zero, one, or many *smaller* buffers to represent a larger chunk of space

Comment: The snippet is rather minimal, but has a bug that suggests the reason for the question.  Don't ignore the return value: int length = await reader.ReadAsync(...);

Comment: If you just want some memory to write to, and not an actual array, why not use [MemoryPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=net-6.0)? Even if Memorypool can also return oversized buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. When using pooled arrays, you need to acknowledge that they will be oversized, and you need to act accordingly - i.e. you need to track what portion is used.

If you tried to create a pool of right-sized arrays: you'd almost never get "hits", i.e. very few callers would ask for **exactly** the same size.

So: just track what portion is used. You should be doing this *anyway* - i.e. you almost certainly want to capture the return value of `reader.ReadAsync` (and probably loop, if it works like most reader APIs do). When you know the final size, just slice that off the chunk; for example:

```cs
var memory = buffer.AsMemory();
// ...
memory = memory.Slice(0, totalBytes);
// ..
```

The handy thing here is that `MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray` will still return the same array, so even if you just work with `Memory<byte>` (and don't keep the `byte[]` conveniently available), you can still recycle the array correctly later.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about slicing it. Just a question, is it possible `ReadAsync()` to read less than requested bytes even if the stream length is greater than current stream position + chunk size?

Comment: @Expressingx yes; read/readasync only need to return *at least one byte* or EOF; there is no guarantee that it will fill the buffer you give it

Comment: Something new learned. Appreciate it.